# How to deal with long names in data cleaning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a users database. I want to separate them into two columns to have user1 and user2.
The way I was solving this was to split the names into multiple columns then merge the names to have the two columns of users.

The issue I run into is some names are long and after the split. Those names take some spot on the data frame which makes it harder to merge properly.

| Users |
| --- |
| Maria Melinda Del Valle Justin Howard |
| Devin Craig Jr. Michael Carter III |
| Jeanne De Bordeaux Alhamdi |

After I split the user columns

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maria | Melinda | Del | Valle |  | Justin | Howard |  |  |
| Devin | Craig | Jr. |  | Michael | Carter | III |  |  |
| Jeanne | De | Bordeaux |  | Alhamdi |  |  |  |  |

The expected result is the following

| User1 | User2 |
| --- | --- |
| Maria Melinda Del valle | Justin Howard |
| Devin Craig Jr. | Michael Carter III |
| Jeanne De Bordeaux | Alhamdi |

Comment: How do you split into individual names?

Comment: If you know where to put the blank columns in the first split, why don't you just skip the intermediate step and use that to create the final result?

Comment: Exactly what I thought @Barmar :-)

Comment: once I split using the space delimiter, it automatically put each element into its own cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
def f(sr):
   m = sr.isna().cumsum().loc[lambda x: x < 2]
   return sr.dropna().groupby(m).apply(' '.join)

out = df.apply(f, axis=1).rename(columns=lambda x: f'User{x+1}')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                     User1               User2
0  Maria Melinda Del Valle       Justin Howard
1          Devin Craig Jr.  Michael Carter III
2       Jeanne De Bordeaux             Alhamdi
```

As suggested by @Barmar, If you know where to put the blank columns in the first split, you should know how to create both columns.